# jQuery block moving

Tags: jquery, firefox, animation, google-chrome

I wanna move a div block to the top, so I coded like this:

CSS part:

```
.movingPart{
margin-top:80px;
}
```

jQuery part:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
$('#btn').click(function() {


    $('.movingPart').animate({
        "margin-top":'0px'

    });


});
```

});

it works perfectly in chrome, but doesn't move a little in firefox, why???

thanks in advance

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481288/jquery-animate-issues

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .animate() Issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481288/jquery-animate-issues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [jQuery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/animate#paramsdurationeasingcallback) indicate that you should use camelCase for properties when using animate.

> Note that properties should be
>   specified using camel case, e.g.
>   "marginLeft" instead of "margin-left."