# jquery animation

Tags: jquery

i dont know what is wrong with this code.. it will just don't work even if it has the same syntax with the other one..

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#inner").animate({height:'200',top:'-100'},1000);
  $("#inner").animate({width:'200',margin-left:'-100'},1000);
});
```

you can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qmuYq/3/)..

Comment: hello.. please help.. :( im out of idea on what is going on with my code.. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving without px `$("#inner").animate({width:'200',margin-left:'-250'},1000);`

Or Look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481288/jquery-animate-issues) on SO

It says,

try using "marginTop" instead of "margin-top". Normally when you use the CSS props as "border-something" or "margin-something" is better to use the "normalized" version of it, as you used to do it in DHTML (styles.marginTop).

So change it to,
`$("#inner").animate({width:'200',marginLeft:'-250'},1000);`

Or

you can also use redsquare's answer...

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the margin-left attribute since the hyphen is a reserved js operator.

See [update](http://jsfiddle.net/qmuYq/6/) to your demo

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("#inner").animate({height:'200',top:'-100'},1000);
  $("#inner").animate({width:'200','margin-left':'-100'},1000);
});
```