# How to set multiple css using jquery animate function

Tags: jquery, css

suppose i have css like

```
position: fixed;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -100px;
margin-top: -50px;
```

this css i need to set from jquery animate function for div. is it possible.
i know the use of jquery animate function like

```
$(".ui-dialog").animate({
left: viewportwidth / 2 - $(".ui-dialog").outerWidth() / 2, 
top: viewportheight / 2 - $(".ui-dialog").outerHeight / 2
}, 1000);
```

thanks

Comment: What would you like to animate? For instance, `position:fixed` cannot be animated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create the CSS as a class:

```
div.myClass {

    position: fixed;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -50px;

}

div.newClass {

    position: fixed;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -50px;

}
```

Then dynamically add the class to the DIV element by using jQuery `addClass()`

```
$("div#myDiv").addClass("myClass");
```

This assumes that your DIV has the ID of myDiv like so:

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

If you need to animate from it's current class to another one, you can use the [switchClass()](http://jqueryui.com/docs/switchClass/) function:

This is an example of changing the class on a binding to a button

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#button" ).click(function(){
        $( "div#myDiv" ).switchClass( "myClass", "newClass", 1000 );
    return false;   
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible but take care of two things:

1. You can't animate `position:fixed`. (Quote from [jQuery `.animate()`
   manual](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)):

   > most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic
   >   jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be
   >   animated but background-color cannot be

   Use classes to handle this.
2. Use `marginTop` and `marginLeft` instead of `margin-top` and
   `margin-left`. (Quoted from [Ricardo Vega's answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481288/jquery-animate-issues/481322#481322)):

   > try using "marginTop" instead of "margin-top". Normally when you use
   >   the CSS props as "border-something" or "margin-something" is better to
   >   use the "normalized" version of it, as you used to do it in DHTML
   >   (styles.marginTop).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code working with me as it is :)

But if you use "viewportwidth" & "viewportheight" with "px" or "em" or what ever, use ".parseInt()" to eliminate unit :)

My code is :

```
var viewportwidth = 120;
var viewportheight = 120;
$(".ui-dialog").animate({
left: viewportwidth / 2 - $(".ui-dialog").outerWidth() / 2 +"px", 
top: viewportheight / 2 - $(".ui-dialog").outerHeight() / 2 +"px"
}, 1000);

});
```

BTW, I see you miss parentheses after "outerHeight" and the code working me with & without `+"px"` in FF, I hope I understood you correctly .

Comment: @RobW well, that's good, maybe they solve it later, when I was learning JQuery, I saw tutorial that I must solve that using parseInt() :) so I said that here :)